# how to remove jumping lines in google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, polyline

I am drawing polyline based on latitude and longitude of user location but the line is jumping and connecting the location where I started the map.

**To get location update**

```
 private fun getLocationUpdates() {

 mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())
 mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
 mLocationRequest.interval = 5000
 mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 1000
 //        mLocationRequest.smallestDisplacement = 170f // 170 m = 0.1 mile
 mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY //set according to your app function
 locationCallback = object: LocationCallback() {
     override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult ? ) {
         locationResult ? : return

         if (locationResult.locations.isNotEmpty()) {
             // get latest location
             val location =
                 locationResult.lastLocation
             onNewLocation(location)
             // use your location object
             // get latitude , longitude and other info from this
         }


     }
 } }
```

**In newlocation method i am adding latlong to list**

```
    private fun onNewLocation(location: Location) {
    Log.i(sarath, "New location: $location")
    mLastKnownLocation = location
    if (!mInitialZoom && location != null)
        initialZoom(location)
    if (isLocationUpdateStarted) {
        if (location != null) {
            mLatLngCollection.add(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude))
        }
        addPoly()
    }
}
```

**adding LatLong to polyline or polygon**

```
    private fun addPoly() {
    if (mLatLngCollection.size != 0) {
        if (mIsPolygon) {
            mPolygonOptions.addAll(mLatLngCollection)
            mPolygonOptions.strokeWidth(7 f)
            mPolygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
            mPolygonOptions.fillColor(Color.CYAN)
            mMap.addPolygon(mPolygonOptions)
        } else {
            mPolylineOptions.addAll(mLatLngCollection)
            mMap.addPolyline(mPolylineOptions)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: image1]

but when I store that **lat long** and then if I retrieve load it to google map polyline means I am getting a single line. `why it is jumping from starting point to the current location at live location` `and how to fix this`, **Any help to draw decent polyline?**[image: image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points to make to explain your results - I used the Polyline as an example but would apply to polygon as well:

### (1)

Live: you continue to add a point (current reported location) to a list - and then add the entire list as a new polyline.  So assuming your reported locations were numbered (1,2,3...) then after 10 location updates you would have 10 polylines consisting of:

```
PL1  = (1)
PL2  = (1,2)
PL3  = (1,2,3)
PL4  = (1,2,3,4)
PL5  = (1,2,3,4,5)
PL6  = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
PL7  = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
PL8  = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
PL9  = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
PL10 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

To fix that you have two choices - but first when you add the polyline (or polygon) *save the result* in a variable:

```
mAddedPolyLine = mMap.addPolyline(mPolylineOptions)
```

So the 1st choice is to keep replacing the points of the polyline with updated location (this overwrites (sets) and is not additive).

```
mAddedPolyline.setPoints(mLatLngCollection)
```

Or, 2nd choice is to remove the polyline and re-add:

```
mAddedPolyline.remove()
// then add as above
```

(This removes previous polyline and adds a new one on every update.)

Saved: Assuming you saved the last latlng list and added it on restart then it would be P10 (from above) which is one list (with still erratic measurements - see next).

### (2)

Second, the erratic layout of your line is a result of measurement noise.  To quantify it use the location.getAccuracy() (in meters) - it will likely be > 10.

How to overcome measurement noise?  Smoothing is one approach or again use the accuracy value and some visual aid (like the fuzzy blue dot on Maps - its gets bigger with more noise.)

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my jumping problem. thanks @Andy

```
private fun addPoly() {
  if (mLatLngCollection.size != 0) {
    if (mIsPolygon) {
      mMap.addPolygon(PolygonOptions().addAll(mLatLngCollection).strokeWidth(7f).strokeColor(Color.GREEN).fillColor(Color.YELLOW))
    } else {
      mPolylineOptions.addAll(mLatLngCollection)
      mMap.addPolyline(
      PolylineOptions().addAll(mLatLngCollection).width(7f).color(Color.GREEN))
    }
  }
}
```